# IE 9/10/11 not rendering images after some unknown threshold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am building an app that pulls files from SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint 2010 for view in HTML.  In C#, files are pulled out of SharePoint (multipage documents like Word, Excel, PDF, TIFF, etc), then are fed into various 3rd party software (DataLogics and Aspose) - which break the documents down into their individual pages, then streams the individual pages to the browser in PNG format.

So in HTML, we have an img element whose src is set to a specific URL in an ASHX service.  The ASHX service grabs the file out of SharePoint and, based on query string params, returns the desired page as a Stream.

Here is how we shoot it back:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "url")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class FileTransfer : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        var stream = GetStream(context.Request);
        int chunkSize = 2097152; //2MB
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        do {
            bytesRead = stream.Read(chunk, 0, chunkSize);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

This works perfectly 100% of the time in any browser when the file we are breaking down comes directly from SharePoint.

We also provide a feature where the user can upload a document.  This is where the problem comes in.  Uploaded documents are not saved in SharePoint.  Instead their data is stored in SessionState until the user chooses to save.  Files are uploaded to an ASMX service, then the browser requests their individual pages via the above ASHX.

Files are uploaded like this in an ASMX service:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
Public object Upload()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (request.Files.Count == 1)
    {
        var uniqueId = request["uniqueId"];
        var file = request.Files[0];

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            docInfo = UploadItem(uniqueId, pageNum, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

UploadItem adds the uniqueId and byte[] to SessionState.

Files are sent from javascript like this (FileUpload being tied to the change event of an input of type=file):

```
this.FileUpload = function (files) {
    var upload = new XMLHttpRequest();
    upload.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this._curUploadRequest.readyState == 4) {
            // handle response
        }
    };

    UpdateFormDigest((<any>window)._spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl,(<any>window)._spFormDigestRefreshInterval);

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("uniqueId", uniqueId);
    data.append("pageNum", pageNum);
    data.append("data", files[0]);

    upload.open('POST', "myurl");
    upload.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest", $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val());
    upload.send(data);
};
```

**Now we come to the actual bug.**

Images are rendered using:

```
<img src="url to ASHX service" />
```

In FireFox and Chrome, page images from uploaded documents always show up just fine.  But in IE (9, 10, or 11), it renders only the first portion of them, then shows broken image icons on the image placeholders.  For these broken images, the NET tab of IE shows it received 0kb and the error event is hit.  But if I put a breakpoint in the ASHX just before it returns the stream, it always has a size.

More interestingly, if you take the url that the src is pointed to, open a new window and paste it in, the image shows up just fine.

I even tried to load the images in javascript first like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
   // use jquery to append image to page
};
img.src = "url to ASHX service";
```

In this scenario, Chrome and Firefox work fine as usual, but IE fails again.  Except this way, the NET tab of IE shows it received the correct size kb in response.  However, it still shows the broken image icon and won't render images to the screen after some unknown threshold.  The first several images come back, but once one breaks, all of the rest break.

I also modified the ASHX service to return base64 data instead of a stream, then bound the base64 to the src.  In the debugger you can see the base64 assigned to the src of the img elements that show the broken image icon.  So the data is there for sure, but IE just isn't rendering it...

I tried to recreate this problem outside of our SharePoint environment in this fiddle using knockout JS.  Basically, I grab a ton of big images and throw them on the screen with each button click.  But it works just fine.  It works perfectly if I use jQuery too.

http://jsfiddle.net/bsdez92f/

Not sure where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the image size was causing a problem.  I scaled the images down to thumbnail size on the server side and returned that to the browser.  All is working fine at this point.